# Resolving Controller constructor dependencies in Asp.Net MVC Unit Tests with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am unsure how to use Ninject to automatically resolve constructor dependencies for my controllers in my unit tests.

In my actual application I have setup my dependency injection in my gloabl.asax as follows:

```
public void SetupDependencyInjection()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<ISomeService>().To<SomeService>();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
    }
```

I have a contoller with a constructor:

```
public SomeController (ISomeService someService)
```

This all works fine, somehow magically the SomeController constructor gets called with someService as an argument. I have no idea how I would replicate this behaviour in my unit tests though. That is, I would like to configure my unittests so that I don't have to create my controllers via the constructor myself - I'd like ninject to do this in much the same way it does it in the real application.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how I would replicate this behaviour in my unit tests though

In your unit test you could use a mocking framework such as [Rhino Mocks](https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-mocks) or [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) to generate mock objects for your dependencies and define expectations on them.

Example with Rhino Mocks:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Something()
{
    // arrange
    var serviceMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISomeService>();
    serviceMock.Stub(x => x.SomeMethod(123)).Return("foo bar");
    var sut = new SomeController(serviceStub);

    // act
    var actual = sut.SomeAction();

    // assert
    // TODO: assert on the result
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but that is not really what I mean. I want to completely get away from having to manually call "new SomeController(serviceStub); " I want to replicate what the MVC DependencyResolver (which is using NinjectDependencyResolver) is doing to resolve dependencies.

Comment: @bplus, you don't do this in a unit test. I think you are missing the point of unit testing layers of your application in isolation. If you use a dependency resolver in your unit test you will basically be injecting concrete implementations of your controllers making strong coupling between what you are trying to unit test and other layers of your application which is something that you should not do in a unit test. In a unit test you want to have full control over the dependencies of the subject under test. That's why you use a mocking framework.